# QDoubleSpinBox with mouse scroll signal in Qt 5?

Tags: qt, qt5, mouseevent, qspinbox

I'm using Qt 5. I have a QDoubleSpinBox, when I hover over it with a mouse, each scroll will increase/decrease 1 from the current value. What I want is to redefine the scroll event and set rules to it. For example, if the current value is 1, I want to set the step to 0.2 instead of 1 when I do down scroll, so it will go like 1->0.8->0.6->0.4.

This is how I connect the signal and slot.

```
connect(MyPreview.mySpinBox, SIGNAL(wheelEvent()), this, SLOT(slotSpinBoxWheelEvent()) )
```

The `slotSpinBoxWheelEvent` function will be handling the custom rules, I just need my spinbox to detect the mouse scroll signal, but the Qt document listed that the QDoubleSpinBox class doesn't have a wheelEvent signal. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such signal as `wheelEvent`, it is protected method in base class `QWidget` and you can reimplement it in your derived class:

```
class MySpinBox : public QDoubleSpinBox {
   // ...
   void wheelEvent (QWheelEvent* e) {
      // do sth here
   }
};
```

If you want to get the step `0.2` in range `[0.0, 1.0]` you should use `setRange` and `setSingleStep` methods of QDoubleSpinBox class.

```
QDoubleSpinBox* sb = new QDoubleSpinBox();
sb->setRange (0.0, 1.0);
sb->setSingleStep (0.2);
```

and now while scrolling spin box you can get only 6 values (0,0.2,0.4 etc).

**EDIT**

so use `value()` method to check current value of SpinBox and if this value is < 1.0 set singleStep to 0.2 otherwise to 1.0

```
void wheelEvent (QWheelEvent* e)
{
    QDoubleSpinBox::wheelEvent (e);

    if (value() >= 1.0)
    {
        // additinal code to check is singleStop is not 1.0
        this->setSingleStep (1.0);
    }
    else
    {
        // additionl code to avoid overriding 0.2 value 
        this->setSingleStep (0.2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want something like if current value is less than 1, set step to 0.2. If it's greater than 1, set step to 1.

Comment: I have several spinboxes in my class, spinboxA and spinboxB, and I want spinboxA to use the normal wheelEvent and spinboxB to use my modified wheelEvent. So I will have to reimplement the spinbox class like your first example, and then declared each spinbox like this? `QDoubleSpinBox spinboxA;` `MySpinBox spinboxB;`?

Comment: @reddy Yes, you can do it in this way, use original *spinbox* and your extended version.

Comment: Hi I got stuck again on the logic. The logic above works except when I'm at value 1.0 and moving down. The value will jump straight from 1.0->0.0 instead of 1.0->0.8->0.6...

Comment: @reddy yea, you are right, we can use `delta()` method of `QWheelEvent` to check in which direction we scroll up/down. If we scroll forward and value is 1.0 we set step to 1.0 otherwise 0.2. If we scroll backward and value is 1.0 we need to set step to 0.2 - `if (e->delta() > 0) { if (value() >= 1.0) setSingleStep(1.0); else setSingleStep(0.2); } else  { if (value() <= 1.0) setSingleStep(0.2); else setSingleStep(1.0); }` , *e* is parameter of `wheelEvent` method. if `delta() > 0` we scroll up, otherwise down. Remember to set initial step less than 1.0, for example `2.0`.

Comment: This still doesn't quite work. If I scroll up from 0.6->0.8->1.0, and then scroll back down again, it will jump from 1.0->0 again.

Comment: Then same issue when I scroll down from 2.0->1.0, then scroll right back up, it will end up with 1.0->1.2->2.2.

Comment: @reddy it is more difficult than i thought :) i have another solution, tested:  this is code in *wheelEvent* method `double d = value(); if (d>1.0 && e->delta()>0) { d = ceil(d); setValue(d); } if (d>1.0 && e->delta()<0) { d = floor(d); setValue(d);}` set **singlestep** to 0.2. Then we need only to test current value, if it is > 1 for example 1.2, we use `ceil` to convert it to 2.0, 2.2 - > 3.0, 3.2 -> 4.0 etc. When scrolling down we use `floor` to convert 2.8 -> 2.0, 1.8 -> 1.0 etc. If current value is < 1.0 we don't need to cast anything.

Comment: Thank you it works! My mindset was stuck on that SetSingleStep loop hole and couldn't pull out.